# Can you blind-fire from cover in Far Cry 3? If so, how?

Tags: far-cry-3

One of the loading screen tips in Far Cry 3 says "Use cover while reloading. You can also blind-fire and peek-and-shoot from cover."

I haven't seen options to do either of these things, and I'm wondering if maybe the tip is incorrect.

**Can you blind-fire from cover in Far Cry 3?  If so, how?**

Comment: I haven't played in a few days, but dont you just get against some cover and pull the trigger?  ( not aiming down your sights )

Comment: @ZeroStack - Wow, you're right. That was never explained well enough to me. Post that and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments earlier, **Yes you can blind-fire from cover in Far Cry 3.**

**The tips shown in the loading screens are correct.**

To do so, get behind any cover that your weapon can shoot over or shoot around.  Then just simply hold down the button mapped to shoot your weapon! (*By default: either* `Right Trigger` or `Left click` *depending on which console you are playing on*)

Note: Be sure **not** to aim down your sights ! If you aim down your sights, your whole body will be exposed and vulnerable to the enemy.  Also note, that while blind fire may help during hectic fire fights, bullets can still travel through some cover! So be weary of what you are using as cover.

Blind fire also works with grenades!

Comment: I never knew about this !!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. To blind-fire, crouch behind cover, and press fire without aiming with your sights.

Comment: How?  We don't really like short one line answers, so please explain your answer fully.

Comment: How is this wrong?  He's explaining how to blindfire: crouch, then fire without aiming.  I don't see what else is there to explain.